# Showing an ACF field in admin posts dashboard

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Looking for a way to display a post's ACF data in admin columns using `manage_posts_columns` hook.

In my `functions.php` I have this:

```
function custom_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'featured_image' => 'Image',
        'categories' => 'Categories',
        'amazon_url' => 'Amazon Link',
        'comments' => '<span class="vers"><div title="Comments" class="comment-grey-bubble"></div></span>',
        'date' => 'Date'
     );
    return $columns;
}

add_filter('manage_posts_columns' , 'custom_columns');

function custom_columns_data( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
    case 'featured_image':
        the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
        break;
    case 'amazon_url' :
         echo get_field( 'product_url', $post_id );
         break;
    }
}

add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_columns_data', 10, 2 );
```

I want the ACF field which is `product_url` for each post appear in the admin dashboard of the post list, the column 'Amazon Link' is there however it seems like the data isn't getting there at all.

Comment: While posting this I noticed that I had the spelling of `amazon` incorrect in `case 'anazon..'` so I thought it was the problem, but I just fixed the mistake and its still the same.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked perfectly fine:

```
  function custom_columns( $columns ) {
        $columns = array(
            'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'featured_image' => 'Image',
            'categories' => 'Categories',
            'amazon_url' => 'Amazon Link',
            'comments' => '<span class="vers"><div title="Comments" class="comment-grey-bubble"></div></span>',
            'date' => 'Date'
         );
        return $columns;
    }

    add_filter('manage_posts_columns' , 'custom_columns');

    function custom_columns_data( $column, $post_id ) {
        switch ( $column ) {
        case 'featured_image':
            the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
            break;
        case 'amazon_url' :
             echo get_field( 'product_url', $post_id );
             break;
        }
    }

    add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_columns_data', 10, 2 );
```

I realize that there was a spelling error at

`case 'anazon_url' :` (I updated it in the question though)

It was `case 'anazon_url' :`

Even after fixing the typo it didn't work but then I cleared caches and tried again and it was working!

So I am leaving the code here so if anyone wants to display ACF data in admin columns here you go!